# Transitioning Jira Issue with resolution

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I want to transition a jira issue to done and put a resolution along with it.

I am using the [POST /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=2.56208738.816289002.1501686048-674717429.1499808162#api/2/issue-doTransition) REST call.

Sample input according to documentation:

```
{
    "update": {
        "comment": [
            {
                "add": {
                    "body": "Bug has been fixed."
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "fields": {
        "assignee": {
            "name": "bob"
        },
        "resolution": {
            "name": "Fixed"
        }
    },
    "transition": {
        "id": "5"
    },
    "historyMetadata": {
        "type": "myplugin:type",
        "description": "text description",
        "descriptionKey": "plugin.changereason.i18.key",
        "activityDescription": "text description",
        "activityDescriptionKey": "plugin.activity.i18.key",
        "actor": {
            "id": "tony",
            "displayName": "Tony",
            "type": "mysystem-user",
            "avatarUrl": "http://mysystem/avatar/tony.jpg",
            "url": "http://mysystem/users/tony"
        },
        "generator": {
            "id": "mysystem-1",
            "type": "mysystem-application"
        },
        "cause": {
            "id": "myevent",
            "type": "mysystem-event"
        },
        "extraData": {
            "keyvalue": "extra data",
            "goes": "here"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm only interested in the fields transition and resolution. My sample input is :

```
{
    "fields": {
        "resolution": {
          "name": "Done"
        }
    },
    "transition": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

I'm getting a 400 with the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessages": [],
  "errors": {
    "resolution": "Field 'resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
  }
}
```

Can someone please point me what I'm missing?

[image: UI to show the resolutions options.]

Comment: Do you have the resolution "Done" available in your screen?

Comment: Yes, I do have resolution "Done". Added an image. @RobertoRusso

Comment: Does the ID 1 matches the status "Done"?

Comment: Aha! Bingo! Thats what I was missing!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the status that matches the ID 1 is not the status "Done" that should  accept, in your screen, the resolutions you're trying to set.

Answer (score 1):

The **Resolution** and **Status** are two different things. *Done* is a (default) Status to which the Issue will be transitioned according to the Transition ID you're sending. The **Resolution** is just a string, a custom field whose value you can change in the *Edit* screen.. and according to the error, one that you don't have specified in that project.

Comment: I understand status and resolution are not the same. My status gets set properly with `"transition": {
        "id": "1"
    }`. Issue is with setting resolution. Isnt `"fields": {
        "resolution": {
          "name": "Done"
        }
    },` enough for setting the resolution?

Comment: @AnkitChaudhari Is it stil relevant?  Since i am also trying to set 2 different values for Status an Resolution and still looking for a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the transition Id using this API

`https://your_company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueId}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields`

in the below response i am interested for Closed Status ..hence i need to get the ID for Closed Status, which is 21.in the Jira UI its in second list so i can use second item form the response of the above API.

[image]

[image]

After that i can use below transition API for status Update with comments (as comment is mandatory for my case)

```html
curl --location --request POST 'https://your_host.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueId}/transitions' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
--header 'x-atlassian-token: no-check' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--data-raw '{
  "update": {
    "comment": [
      {
        "add": {
          "body": "-"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    "transition": {
        "id": "21"
    }
}'
```

#make sure you have jq utility install in commandline "brew install jq"

```bash
Here is the Complete shell script to Handle transition process 


#!/bin/bash

export JIRA_USER='your_jira_email_id'
export JIRA_PERSONAL_TOKEN='Your Jira Personal Token'
export HOST='your_company_host'
#Generate your Personal Access Token 'https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens'"

function get_transition_id() {
  jira_issue_id=$1
  response=$(
    curl -X --location --request GET https://"${HOST}".atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"${jira_issue_id}"/transitions?expand=transitions.fields \
      --header 'accept: */*' \
      --header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
      --header 'x-atlassian-token: no-check' \
      --user "$JIRA_USER:$JIRA_PERSONAL_TOKEN"
  )
# Here you need to manually check transitions[] values at which index 'Closed' present , in my case second index contains Closed
  transition_id=$(echo $response | jq -r ".transitions[1].id")

  transition_to_close "${jira_issue_id}" "${transition_id}"
}

function transition_to_close() {
  jira_issue_id=$1
  transition_id_close=$2
  response=$(curl --location --request POST https://"${HOST}".atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"${jira_issue_id}"/transitions \
    --header 'accept: */*' \
    --header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
    --header 'x-atlassian-token: no-check' \
    --user "$JIRA_USER:$JIRA_PERSONAL_TOKEN" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
  "update": {
    "comment": [
      {
        "add": {
          "body": "-"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    "transition": {
        "id": "'"${transition_id_close}"'"
    }
}')

}

function close_jira_ticket() {
  jira_issue_id=$1

  # Transition Ticket Status to Close
  get_transition_id "$jira_issue_id"
}

close_jira_ticket "YOUR_JIRA_ISSUE_ID"
```