# How I can change or clear value for Resolution field in Jira using Python?

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I really cannot change resolution for my issues ! Can you please help me ?

```py
jira = jira.connect()
issue = jira.issue(my_issue)
     
jira.transition_issue(issue.key, '1311', resolution={'id': '10306'})
```

Where: `1311` - transition is `"Complete"`, `10306` - resolution is `"Completed"`

I receive:

```
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"resolution":"Field 
    'resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or 
    unknown."}}
```

I want to:

- Change of the resolution
- To remove resolution value at all

Answer (score 3):

I was able to close issue and change resolution with below code.

```py
issue = jira.issue(str(sys.argv[3]))
jira.transition_issue(issue, transition='Close', resolution={'name':'Cannot Reproduce'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly change an Issue's resolution state.

It's the same as the web interface; you have to apply the appropriate workflow transition that causes the Issue to become complete; IE. changing the Status field to 'Done' or whatever the workflow says is the criteria for being completed

Comment: Yes I tried to update resolution but i got the same error message as above. However I have resolved in another way ..you can find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74773166/3740432

Answer (score 0):

*Clearing* is not implemented, but a feature request has been opened at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-75100 (with related request on GUI at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-11444).